# Fancy XML or name/value pairs on save of data to SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP application for student grading with a paper (with an ID and a userID) that requires a grade and scores from several different criteria (criteria 1, score 1, criteria 2, score 2)

I wonder if I should put this in XML and push it into SQL Server as XML or convert the name/value pairs to a delimited string and just parse it out within the stored proc.

The data structure looks like this:

```
<DocumentCriteria> <Document grader="95" documentGUID="{B49654E7-9AF2-4B89-AF8F-5146F7CD4911}" graderFYC="5907"><criterion cnumber="1" rank="3"/><criterion cnumber="3" rank="3"/></Document></DocumentCriteria>'
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not parse the XML in SQL Server?

That is:

1. use the XML to pass multi-row data to SQL Server
2. [shred and store relationally](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#XML)

Of course, if you never need to query or search the data then you could store the XML, but then why store it of you won't use it?